# How can I push to an array that’s inside an object's element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object:

`var watchObject = {};`

Here is the following code I'm trying to accomplish; if it exists in the object I want to append it and if it doesn't exist I want to create a new key/value pair. The key value pair looks like "23": [blah]. So if the "23"(data.room) exists in the object I will push another to it like "23":[blah,bleh].

```
//assume data.room is defined elsewhere and data.videoId is defined elsewhere

if (data.room in watchObject) {
    watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId);
} else {
    watchObject[data.room] = data.videoId;
}
```

I tried the above, I thought it would work, but it keeps saying:

"TypeError: watchObject[data.room].push is not a function"

I've also tried assigning *data.room* into a variable without any luck:

```
if (data.room in watchObject) {
   let tempRoom = data.room;
   watchObject.tempRoom.push(data.videoId);
   //watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId);
} else {
    watchObject[data.room] = data.videoId;
}
```

And I get this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: `watchObject.tempRoom.push(data.videoId);` looks for a property named `tempRoom` on `watchObject`. It is completely different from `watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId);`. which looks for a property named the same as the value of `data.room`. `watchObject[tempRoom].push(data.videoId);` would have had the same effect as the original. See [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `watchObject[data.room]` is `blah` (i.e. videoId) rather than `[blah]` (i.e. array of videoIds] hence the error `push is not a function` because a string won't have a push method.

You need this:

```
if(watchObject[data.room] == null) {
  watchObject[data.room] = []
}
// now you can safely push to the array
watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this is downvoted, I tried this approach and it worked out for me. Thank you I appreciate it!

Comment: i think it was downvoted by someone because there is a correction required in your answer. Made some edits thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that once you create the entry via this code...

> ```js
> watchObject[data.room] = data.videoId;
> ```

it is *not* an array so the next time you try this code...

> ```js
> watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId);
> ```

it will fail with the error you see.

A simple option here is to lazily create an array before pushing

```js
const watchObject = {};
const arr = [{ room: "23", videoId: "blah" }, { room: "23", videoId: "bleh" }];

arr.forEach((data) => {
  // create an empty array if it does not exist
  watchObject[data.room] ??= [];

  // now push
  watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId);
});

console.log(watchObject);
```

See [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)

Comment: Thank you for the info on the ??= operator I didn't know that was a thing. I will mark Dusan's as the answer simply because it is more intuitive at first glance without knowing the operator. But this is good to know. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You're almost done. But you have a mistake. Try this:

```
let watchObject = {};

// Init `data`
if (watchObject[data.room]) {
  watchObject[data.room].push(data.videoId);
} else {
  watchObject[data.room] = [data.videoId]; // this is the line you need to change
}
```

This will work well.